# Classification of unnecessary pauses in a telephone call

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, modeling, feature-engineering

So I'm working on a project where I'm interested in classifying a call as having excessive unnecessary pauses.

This call has two speakers. And  I also have the timestamps for each dialogue uttered by each speaker.

Now, It's not hard for me to calculate the duration of these pauses since I have the time steps, but I might be lacking some insight as to how to encode them. They can be of different lengths and scattered around different parts of the calls, with some being more dense and others, not so much.

Also, It turns out that whether the speaker gives an intimation prior to taking a break from the call has an effect on the pause being unnecessary or not.

Furthermore, it's the reason for taking a break and thus incurring the pause that's also imperative in determining the admissibility of these pauses. So, I might also have to feed in to my model, the sentence encodings prior to a pause.

I'm looking for some analysis on my thought process and of course, any suggestions are welcome

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of suggestions/feedback you're looking for. Could you edit to make the question more specific? One big issue here is that you need to distinguish unnecessary pauses from normal ones. How do you plan to do this, even if you have a full transcript of the call?

Comment: Do you plan to use multiple coders and then perform some inter-rate reliability calculations?  Otherwise, how would you have any confidence that you've been able to correctly identity normal pauses from abnormal ones?

Comment: @user20160 I did some EDA and the distinction with pause times alone wasn't pronounced. But I started reading the corresponding dialogues and came to the conclusion that communicating those pauses and especially telling the other speaker why you're going to be away for a while made the pause admissible. An example could be one of someone taking an order for a delivery. Now as the speaker takes the order and aren't sure about having sufficient inventory could tell the other person that they'll be checking in with someone who's sure about the supplies being in stock, and thus tell them to hold.